# Powershell Monitor Clipboard Change

Tags: powershell, events, powershell-5.0, powershell-core

I'm trying monitor clipboard change by powershell, and not consider to use comparing (Get-Clipboard) before and after change because it cannot distinguish between "two copy are identical" and "haven't make new copy action yet".

So I tried to override WndProc of a dummy-control which is added to the chain of clipboard viewers by winAPI SetClipboardViewer.
But it seems not same as expected.

```
#Include script containing winAPI
.".\Set-ClipboardViewer.ps1" 


class MsgOnlyWin : System.Windows.Forms.Control{



    [void] NotificationFunction()
    {
    Write-Host "Clipboard changed"
    }

    [void] WndProc($m)
    {
        $WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308
        if($m.Msg -eq $WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD){
            NotificationFunction
            break
        }
    }



}


$Con = [MsgOnlyWin]::new()
Set-ClipboardViewer ($Con.Handle)
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with C/C++/C# and use that code in PowerShell if you choose as you are already going down that path. What did you search for?

> [There are lots of samples available for such use cases.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20monitor%20for%20windows%20clipboard%20change&form=ANNTH1&refig=9f4487d430c4436ca0b0f862acf24a6c&sp=-1&pq=c%23%20monitor%20for%20windows%20clipboard%20change&sc=0-39&qs=n&sk=&cvid=9f4487d430c4436ca0b0f862acf24a6c)
>
> [C# Tip: Monitoring Clipboard Activity in C#](https://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3359891/C-Tip-Monitoring-Clipboard-Activity-in-C.htm)
>
> [Monitor for clipboard changes using AddClipboradFormatListener](https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-monitor-for-clipboard-changes-using-addclipboardformatlistener/)
>
> [ClipboardNotification.cs](https://gist.github.com/glombard/7986317)

For all intents and purposes, your question is almost a duplicate of this Stackoverflow thread.

> [How do I monitor clipboard content changes in C#? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226920/how-do-i-monitor-clipboard-content-changes-in-c)